# Between youself and I

Tags: reflexives

I understand that myself and related pronouns are reflexive. I do not think the sentence:
"As a result of previous correspondence between you and me," sounds correct.
I would like to say "As a result of previous correspondence between yourself and I," but I do not know how correct that is.

My understanding is that both pronouns are objects, and neither are reflexive, nor subjective. What is the correct way to say this?

Note that I am trying to sound formal and professional. This is a scientific piece of writing, and not a casual piece.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Using 'I' is unacceptable. Won't '... between us' do? '... between ourselves' is grammatical, but possibly in the grey area between very formal and highfalutin'. // 'Myself' etc are used emphatically as well as reflexively. Check previous posts here.

Comment: "Between you and me" is perfectly OK. See https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/usage/between-you-and-me

Comment: @Kate Bunting 'Perfectly OK' and 'grammatical' aren't exact synonyms. 'As a result of previous correspondence between you and me' sounds very clumsy. And I've just checked your linked article; I believe that is addressing solely the pragmatic usage (cf Between you, me and the gatepost, ...).

Comment: *between us* works, and in my view is better than *between ourselves*

Answer (score 3):

I feel like if you're trying to sound formal and professional, then this is most succinct and appropriate:

> "As a result of our previous correspondence"

This avoids the issue entirely whilst maintaining the style that you're aiming for.

Comment: Thank you to all. I appreciate the speedy responses, and will take your advice. Most namely: "As a result of our previous correspondence"

Comment: But this (1) doesn't answer OP's actual usage question and (2) is proffering writing advice, which is off-topic on ELU. It is, however, useful and sensible advice, and would make a very good 'comment'.

Comment: Very true, but nonetheless the OP accepted it as the answer to their question in the other comment on the answer.